# Basic websocket with Spring without STOMP and SockJS

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I have implemented the following  websocket endpoint

```
@MessageMapping("/socket/{myId}/")
@SendTo("/queue/myqueue")
public MyObject getObject(@DestinationVariable String myId) throws Exception {

    return new MyObject("MyId:" + myId);
}
```

Now how can I send message to that endpoint from one of my service.java class?
There will be front-end client as well, which will read the message from websocket once the service.java class's method send some message to websocket endpoint. I am a little confused that how can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

When using a raw websocket(without STOMP), the message sent lacks of information to make Spring route it to a specific message handler method (we don't have any messaging protocol), so instead of annotating your controller, you'll have to implement a WebSocketHandler by extending **TextWebSocketHandler** 
public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message){
}

Checkout an example here [spring boot websocket without STOMP and SockJs](http://www.devglan.com/faq/spring-websocket-integration-example-without-stomp)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [SimpMessagingTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.html).
For example, if you want to send a message for a specific user from your service class:

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

public void sendMessage(User user, String message) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(user);
    Objects.requireNonNull(message);
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user.getUsername(), "/queue/myqueue", message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that one